# Thymeleaf src returns a loading error

Tags: angularjs, thymeleaf

I am trying to load some videos from the application folder.

I see the video loaded, I can play it but I receive in the browser console this error:

> 404 Error: GET http://localhost:8080/%7B%7BvideoPathsTh[$index]%7D%7D

I thought it was about ng-src but the error persist....

```
{{videoPaths[$index]}}= "/../../../static/videosDir/" and 
 {{{videoPathsTh[$index]}}}= "/../../../videosDir/"
```

**HTML:**

```
<li ng-repeat="video in videos">Video-ul: {{$index+1}} >
        <video
            width="300" controls="controls">
            <source ng-src="{{videoPaths[$index]}}"
                th:src="@{{{videoPathsTh[$index]}}}" type="video/mp4">
            </source>
        </video>
</li>
```

[image]

Comment: is the triple curly brace a thymeleaf thing?

Comment: no....it's from angularjs.....i uploaded a picture....I am in peoplecounter.html. can you tell me how could you go back to videoDirs using ../../../videoDirs? maybe I am wrong with the path

Comment: I updated a picture. can you check it?

Comment: You can certainly use `{{{ }}}` if you set it up in the config, however, your other line is showing you use the default `{{ }}`..so which is it? Try changing your path variables. Looking at the screen shot its `../../videosDir`

Comment: if I use a simple string in the thymeleaf src like ../../videosDir the application is working but if I use {{{ }}} I get that error...so I guess this is the problem.

Comment: get rid of the third curly brace. It should only be `{{ }}`. On another note, if you use a src attribute you will get a 404 even though it loads because of the way html and the dom naturally work. It will try and load the literal string version before loading the angular interpolated string. Search ngSrc for more info on that

Comment: And now that I reread your original question, the above is exactly what is happening

Comment: also ng-src does not work on videos https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1352

Comment: the third {} is from Thymeleaf. I read this: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html

Comment: If I do this: th:src="{{videoPathsTh[$index]}}" I get : 
     org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "{{videoPathsTh[$index]}}" (peoplecounter:20)

Comment: That is why I asked about the 3 curly braces The first is for thymleaf and the other two are angular. I would think some sort of conflict would happen. Anyway, if your video is loading fine then dont worry about it. Nothing you can do about the 404 since you aren't/cannot use ng-src on video

Comment: It's driving me crazy this topic....now it works later it doesn't

Comment: I tried something: @Override
 public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
  registry.addResourceHandler("/videosDir/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/videosDir/").setCachePeriod(0);
 } and as you can see in the question's  picture videosDir is in the root and I created a resource handler for that folder and if I try this it doesn't work:  <source src="/videosDir/atrium.mp4" th:src="@{/videosDir/atrium.mp4}" type="video/mp4">
    </source> WHY?/?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146913/discussion-between-progismetal-and-ronnie).